# Postgres SQL: How to create a constraint to check an element is not in an array of string

Tags: arrays, postgresql, constraints

I'm learning about constraints, and I haven't found the way to check if a value is in an array.

Here s my problem:

`City`: `text`
`Other_cities`: array of `text`

I'd like to say that city must be different of other cities.
I'd like to check other cities are all different

```
ALTER TABLE address 
            ADD CONSTRAINT  "check cities are different"
            CHECK (
            City <> Other_cities
            );
```

I guess this code is wrong as it's not checking every other cities one by one.

How can I do?

Comment: Could you include the schema for `address` please? Are you required to use an array? Normally this would be done with a join table and a unique constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`any`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16) to check if an element is in an array.

```
test=> select not 'Moose Factory' = any( array['Moose Factory', 'Walla Walla'] );
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check that `city` is different from all values in `other_cities`:

```
ALTER TABLE address ADD CHECK ((city <> ALL (other_cities)) IS TRUE);
```

The `IS TRUE` will take care of NULL values in the array. Without it, the constraint would pass arrays that contain a NULL value, because check constraints allow rows where the test evaluates to NULL.